# What did I do wrong with this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> $$e^{3x-2}e^{-x}=4e, \ \text{round to the nearest thousandths}$$

I keep getting $x\approx2.884$ but the answer is $x\approx2.193$. What am I doing wrong? Here is my work:

\begin{align*}
e^{3x-2}e^{-x}&=4e \\ e^{2x-2}&=4e \\ 2x-2\ln(e)&=\ln(4e) \\ 2x-2&=\ln(4e)\\ 2x&=\ln(4e)+2 \\ x&=\frac{\ln(4e)+2}{2} \\ x&\approx2.884
\end{align*}

I've tried looking at $e^{-x}$ as $\frac{1}{e^x}$ or calculating the exact value of some of the simpler natural logs, but I keep getting the same answer. I feel like the mistake I'm making is so ridiculously obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

**UPDATE:** I discovered my mistake was an error of notation. I did not properly include parentheses on the last step on my calculator, and therefore my calculator assumed I was computing $\frac{\ln(4)e+2}{2}$

Comment: In my calculator, $(\ln(4e) + 2) / 2$ is approximately $2.193$. I don't see any mistake in your calculation.

Comment: In your third line of computation, you presumably mean $(2x-2)\ln(\mathrm{e})$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson He/she could have meant that, but it's possible he could have meant what he/she wrote. Nonetheless, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I probably should utilize parentheses more often, but yes that is what I meant. It doesn't make much of a difference though, considering $\ln (e)=1$.

Comment: @paulinho If the asker cannot properly write a line of mathematics, then it is likely that the error stems from a lack of care in inputting the the final formula into a calculator or computer.  While the fact that $\ln(\mathrm{e})=1$ means that the mistake doesn't ultimately matter, the lack of care *does* matter.

Comment: Update: I just realized my calculator only gave me the wrong answer because I didn't use parentheses on the last step.

Comment: How do you get $\frac {\ln 4e + 2}2 = 2.884$?  $e = 2.7183$ and $4e = 10.8732$ and $\ln 4e = 2.3863$ and $\frac {\ln 4e + 2}2 = 2.1932$.  But you should have done $\ln 4e = \ln 4 + \ln e = \ln 4 + 1$. And $\ln 4 = 1.386$.

Comment: @fleablood Read the update in the original post

Comment: $\frac {\ln (4e + 2)}2$ would be $1.278$ so that *isn't* what you entered into the calculator.  $\frac {(\ln 4)*e + 2} 2 = 2.884$ and *that* was what you were entering.  I was going to say Xander Henerson was being too harsh but now I think he was being just harsh enough.  You *must* be more careful in entering data.  Paranthesis and order are *crucially* important and you really should *not* be making these orders of operation errors.

Comment: Be the way.  $\ln 2 = 0.693$ is the basis of you calculations. $\frac {\ln 4e + 2}2 = \frac {\ln 4 + 1 + 2}2 = \frac {\ln 2^2 + 1+ 2}2 = \frac {2\ln 2 + 1+ 2}2 = \ln 2 + 0.5 + 1 = 0.693 +0.5 + 1 = 2.193$

Comment: You could simplify the algebra once further since $\ln(4\mathrm e)+2= \ln4+3$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calculation (last step) step is wrong.

$$ x = \frac{\ln(4e) + 2}{2} = \frac{\ln 2^{2} + \ln e + 2}{2} = \frac{2\ln 2 + 3}{2} = \ln 2 + \frac{3}{2} \approx 2.193 $$

(Also, you should have used parentheses the third step down.)

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by the third line of your computation, you were careless with your parentheses.  What you computed is 
$$ \frac{\ln(4)\cdot\mathrm{e} + 2}{2} \approx 2.884. $$
My guess is that what you typed into the calculator was something like

```
 ( ln 4 * e + 2 ) / 2
```

or possibly

```
 ln 4 * e + 2 / 2
```

depending on what calculator or computer program you are using.

Your [first edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3291529/2) also does not fix the issue.  Your calculator was *not* assuming that you meant
$$ \frac{\ln(4\mathrm{e} + 2)}{2} \approx 2.996. $$
What you meant to calculate was
$$ \frac{\ln(4\mathrm{e}) + 2}{2} \approx 2.193. $$
On most calculators, this would be something like

```
 ( ln ( 4 * e ) + 2 ) / 2
```

Parentheses matter.  Be careful with them.